# Program a sequence of words in a Vector using R

Tags: r, vector

How can you create a vector in **R** which consists of a sequence of different words?

Something like `Vec_Sex`:
for `0` to `6`, input `"Male"` and for `7` to `9`, input `"Female"`...

I know shortcuts like `rep(1:3,times=4)` etc... But even after flicking through my lecture notes and a goole search, I'm unsure how to achieve this with words and when the amount of elements that contain that word differ...

Outcome would be something like:

```
Vec_Sex = [ Male, Male, Male, Male, Male, Male, Male, Female, Female, Female ]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `rep` and `c`. Examples:

```
c(rep("Male", 7), rep("Female", 3))
# [1] "Male"   "Male"   "Male"   "Male"   "Male"   "Male"   "Male"   "Female" "Female" "Female"
rep(c("Male", "Female"), times = c(7, 3))
# [1] "Male"   "Male"   "Male"   "Male"   "Male"   "Male"   "Male"   "Female" "Female" "Female"
```

Note that `times` can be a vector specifying how many times to repeat each element.

Also, note that R starts indexing at 1, not zero.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realise that it starts indexing at one. Thanks for the answer :D

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean this?

```
rep(c("Male","Female"), times = c(7,3))

R> rep(c("Male","Female"), times = c(7,3))
 [1] "Male"   "Male"   "Male"   "Male"   "Male"   "Male"   "Male"   "Female"
 [9] "Female" "Female"
```

`times` can be a numeric vector of length > 1, with the elements applying to the elements in the first argument in turn.