# R: paste element of a vector

Tags: r, vector

I've got the following situation in R:

```
> wordfreq 
  filiaalnummer       filiaal          type  omschrijving   filiaalnaam    
              1            3             3             2             1  
> names(wordfreq)  
 [1] "filiaalnummer" "filiaal"       "type"          "omschrijving" 
 [5] "filiaalnaam" 

> as.numeric(wordfreq)
 [1] 1 3 3 2 1
```

Where each time the number represents the frequency of the word above. I would like to paste the names of the vector into one element with the correct frequency, so I would like to get the following:

```
filiaalnummer filiaal filiaal filiaal filiaal type type type omschrijving omschrijving filiaalnaam
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21171553/program-a-sequence-of-words-in-a-vector-using-r

Answer (score 5):

Try this:

```
rep(names(wordfreq), times = wordfreq)
```

Here is a reproducible example:

```
wordfreq = sample.int(10, 5, replace = TRUE)
names(wordfreq) = letters[1:5]
rep(names(wordfreq), times = wordfreq)
```